# Out of Bound Exception

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a loop that only iterates though a portion of the list that I have, but the list sometimes only has one or two items put into it. My goal is to have it print no more than 3 results, regardless of how many items are inside the loop.

```
if (event.getMessage().getContent().startsWith("!!")) {
                for (int i=0; i<allMatches.size(); i++) {
                    event.getTextChannel().sendMessage((i+1)+".\\) " + allMatches.get(i).replace("\"", "").replace(",", "; ")
                            .replace("[", " ").replace("]", "").replace("english_definitions:", "")).queue();
                }   
            }
            else {
                for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
                    event.getTextChannel().sendMessage((i+1)+".\\) " + allMatches.get(i).replace("\"", "").replace(",", "; ")
                            .replace("[", " ").replace("]", "").replace("english_definitions:", "")).queue();
                }   
            }
```

I understand that the out of bounds error is coming from the i<3 when the list only has 1 or 2 items in it, but the loop keeps going anyway. I've tried various things but I'm not quite sure how to do it correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger. Please help yourself to some complementary debugging techniques. If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to print the smaller of 3 and size amount of times? You could calculate that number prior to your loops so you only have one for loop instead:

```
if (event.getMessage().getContent().startsWith("!!")) {
 for (int i = 0; i < allMatches.size(); i++) {
  event.getTextChannel().sendMessage((i + 1) + ".\\) " + allMatches.get(i).replace("\"", "").replace(",", "; ")
   .replace("[", " ").replace("]", "").replace("english_definitions:", "")).queue();
 }

} else {
 for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(3, allMatches.size()); i++) {
  event.getTextChannel().sendMessage((i + 1) + ".\\) " + allMatches.get(i).replace("\"", "").replace(",", "; ")
   .replace("[", " ").replace("]", "").replace("english_definitions:", "")).queue();
 }
}
```

I changed up the for loop declaration (assuming the 2nd on is the one you need help with?):

`for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(3, allMatches.size()); i++)`

So now it will run 3 or `allMatches.size()` number of times, whichever is smaller.

---

Another optimization to reduce the amount of duplicate code would be to compute the number of times to loop, outside your for loop and only have 1 loop:

```
int loops = Math.min(3, allMatches.size());
if (event.getMessage().getContent().startsWith("!!")) 
    loops = allMatches.size();

for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
  event.getTextChannel().sendMessage((i + 1) + ".\\) " + allMatches.get(i).replace("\"", "").replace(",", "; ")
   .replace("[", " ").replace("]", "").replace("english_definitions:", "")).queue();
 }
```

It is always a good idea to reduce duplicate code for readability purposes and debugging and since it appears both your loops do the same thing, it would be best to restructure your code like I did above to avoid duplicate code.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still quite new to programming, but I knew there had to be a way to optimize a bit.

Comment: No problem, hopefully what I said makes sense

Answer (score 2):

You can use Stream API to solve this:

```
AtomicInteger num = new AtomicInteger(1);// use this for string number
allMatches.stream().limit(3).forEach(value -> event.getTextChannel()
  .sendMessage(num.getAndIncrement()+".\\)"+value.replace("\"", "")
  .replace(",", "; ").replace("[", " ")
  .replace("]", "").replace("english_definitions:", "")).queue()
);
```

With limit method you can iterate thrue only needed count of values and you won't get any problem if size of list is less.

Comment: Please also add some explanation, not just a bunch of code lines. At its current form this is not very helpful for OP to understand the problem and why this is a solution to it.

Answer (score -1):

Add an if clause inside the second loop.

```
if(allMatches.size()==i)break;
```